# PHP SHA 256 Not Producing Expected Output

Tags: php

I have been working a couple of months on some PHP code to generate a hash value from some data input. The task is to take two transaction hashes and hash the two transactions. I am using the sha256 bit algorithm library to do so. The problem I am noticing is the expected result is not coming out.

I tried to:

1. check if the variables were strings (Note: hash() function requires a string for both the algorithm and input variable.
2. The code for the hash function input was output correctly.

I am at a loss as of what the problem is.
Also, I am using files to read in and input the results into an array because PHP refreshes the page thus resulting in losing the data.

The function in PHP I am having trouble with is shown below:

```
function printTransactions($ArrayName, $Name){
            $counter = 1;    
            $BlockNumber = 0;
            $HashesFromFileArray = readfileToArray($Name."Hash.txt");
            array_pop($HashesFromFileArray);  
            foreach ($ArrayName as $LineFromFile){     
                PrintoutToUser("yellow", "3", "Transaction " . $counter . " <font color='white'>" . $LineFromFile . "</font>");                                     
                If ($counter % 2 == 0) {                        
                    $BlockNumber = $BlockNumber + 1;                                
                    if(isset($HashesFromFileArray[$counter -1])=="1" && isset($HashesFromFileArray[$counter -2])=="1" && gettype($HashesFromFileArray[$counter -1])!="NULL"){
                        if(strlen($HashesFromFileArray[$counter -1])>=66 && strlen($HashesFromFileArray[$counter -2])>=66){
                            $HashValueOfBothTransactions = GetNewHash($HashesFromFileArray[$counter -2].$HashesFromFileArray[$counter -1], "sha256");                             
                            $TransactionInputCounter = $counter-1;
                            $TransactionInputCounter2 = $counter;
                            PrintoutToUser("green", "3", "T". $TransactionInputCounter.":" . $HashesFromFileArray[$counter -2]);
                            PrintoutToUser("green", "3", "T". $TransactionInputCounter2.":" . $HashesFromFileArray[$counter -1]);  
                            PrintoutToUser("blue", "3", "Data Hashed " . $HashesFromFileArray[$counter -2].$HashesFromFileArray[$counter -1]." Length of Array input 1 and 2 is " . strLen($HashesFromFileArray[$counter -2]) . " and " . strLen($HashesFromFileArray[$counter -2]));
                            PrintoutToUser("red", "3", "End of Block: " .$BlockNumber . ":". $HashValueOfBothTransactions . "<br />"); 
                            writeToFileDataPlain("TESTING", $HashValueOfBothTransactions); 
                        }                        
                    }                                                                 
                }             
                $counter = $counter + 1;                     
            } 
        }
```

If I was to put in the following:

Blockchain Name: Sean

Sender: Sean

Amount: 2

Receiver: Bob

Nonce: 2

I would expect it to be 6a3ea3befedebacdce2692e91623b23e8e74b9bfff2eedaf4db2470fb3efc6db
after setting two transactions.

I instead get 90189390a229292338f2d6a2e98cec46751ce0ae6b18fa0d3be56681c8cedf44  which is incorrect.

I am not sure why this is occurring and how to fix it at the moment.

My full program can be found at https://github.com/seansanders/PHPSHABlockchain/blob/master/LedgerProgramV4.php

Note, I have left the troubleshooting comments in that are color-coded green for the user.

Some other suspicious things have also occurred in the program:

1) The two transactions hashes being hashed are not producing the correct hash value that is expected.

2) I noticed that the Test File I am writing to is putting more data than expected after submitting three transactions. I think this is a problem directly with the if statements and I am going wrong somewhere.

I have tried my best to adhere to best coding practices and make the code as easy to read as possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may need to go to Code Review in StackExchange...

Comment: Your code is very confuse to understand. You could try to debug and narrow down to a few lines of problem. I advise you to read about PHP PSR's and Clean Code. It will really help you to write better code and therefore isolate the logic and eventually some problems.

Comment: Few people, if any, are going to take the time to review 100+ lines of mostly unrelated code to find the relevant bits. Reduce your code to the absolute minimum required to reproduce the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the solution to the problem was to simply change to using a CSV file. The reason was that the text file was getting some funny characters that I suspect was due to the /r/n. Thanks to all who have helped.